# Mounting filesystem on logical volume inside virtual whole-disk image

Tags: virtualization, mount, disk-image

I have tried to mount a virtual disk image on my Fedora host using the command

```
qemu-nbd -c /dev/ndb0 rawhide.img
```

and then detecting the LVM logical volumes and mounting the one I wanted. Obviously, the virtual machine is not running - I'm not stupid. However, because I have found this to be unreliable (nbd dies after a while), and also slow, I have decided to just copy the filesystem into a subdirectory of my home directory:

```
cp -a /mnt/rawhide .
```

However, I can't even get nbd to stay alive long enough to do the copy! It just died after *less than one minute*!

I can't use the fast offset= technique (at least, not as stated) from [this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Images) because the filesystem is inside LVM on the virtual disk image. I think there was some utility to calculate the offset for you, but I can't remember what it was called, or whether it works with LVM?

Comment: I've filed [a bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=785556).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `guestfish` instead:

```
$ mkdir rawhide
$ sudo guestfish -i rawhide.img

Welcome to guestfish, the libguestfs filesystem interactive shell for
editing virtual machine filesystems.

Type: 'help' for help on commands
      'man' to read the manual
      'quit' to quit the shell

Operating system: Fedora release 17 (Rawhide)
/dev/vg/lv_root mounted on /
/dev/vda2 mounted on /boot
><fs> glob copy-out /* rawhide
```

**Warning:** That actually misses out the hidden files contained in `/`, but I don't really care about them for my purposes.